# Oracle Query For opening and closing balance

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

hi i have following table and data to get opening and closing balance of every account opening balance required  gdate<02-oct-2013 
here is my table

```
 create table ledger (account_no varchar2(10),gdate date,debit number(8),credit number(8))

insert into ledger (account_no,gdate,debit,credit) values ('10-0001','01-oct-2013',1000,0);
  insert into ledger (account_no,gdate,debit,credit) values ('10-0001','24-oct-2013',0,440);
insert into ledger (account_no,gdate,debit,credit) values ('20-0001','01-oct-2013',3000,0);
insert into ledger (account_no,gdate,debit,credit) values ('30-0001','01-oct-2013',300,0);
insert into ledger (account_no,gdate,debit,credit) values ('20-0001','16-oct-2013',1200,0);
insert into ledger (account_no,gdate,debit,credit) values ('30-0001','17-oct-2013',0,1340);
insert into ledger (account_no,gdate,debit,credit) values ('30-0001','24-oct-2013',500,0);
```

i need following result

```
 ACCOUNT_NO OPENING  DEBIT  CREDIT  CLOSING
  10-0001    1000    0       440    560
  20-0001    3000    1200      0    4200
  30-0001     300    500    1340    540
```

Comment: if you have ddl scripts for the tables involved this would save someone some time answering this question and mean that they are not guessing about data types etc. Personally I find SQL Fiddle quite useful for sharing this sort of thing: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: here is table structure  create table ledger (account_no varchar2(10),gdate date,debit number(8),credit number(8))

Comment: Please can you also explain what was wrong with the result. How many rows were you expecting? If you have the DML a sample of this data in as well it would be helpful.

Comment: opening and closing balance always show 0 zero

Comment: What output do you expect for the sample data you posted? I would think you'd only get two rows, with `10-0001,-4860,0,5310,450` and `30-0001,1040,352,20,708`?

Comment: I get two rows when run in SQL Fiddle and neither have a closing balance of zero: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/629ff/3

Comment: First, why are you lagging over closing on both opening and closing columns? I'm not familiar with this keyword, so just wondering if it was being used correctly. Also, I think you might be creating a 0 OPEN column as literally, select 0, with column name as OPEN. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/10c00/13. What are you trying to do with Open / Close, create a cursor, or create a column of 0's?

Comment: The numbers I suggested above came [from this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1524c/1), incidentally; I'm not sure if that's what you actually want though so I won't make it an answer yet. Aside from your `lag` choice looking very odd, I think you're filtering the dates too early - this version works out all the balances and then applies the date filter. I think you probably want accounts with no changes in the period as well though, maybe.

Comment: i need to get opening balance in sql query account_no 10-0001 opening balance is 5860 how to get this

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP keep moving th goal posts

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment because it doesn't answer the question.  Your query simplifies to:

```
Select account_no, LAG(closing, 1 ,0) OVER (order by account_no) as opening,
       debit, credit,
       (LAG(closing,1,0) OVER (order by account_no )+ closing) as closing
from (select account_no, 0 as OPEN, SUM(debit) as debit, SUM(credit) as credit,
             sum(debit) - sum(credit) as closing
      FROM ledger
      where gdate > '20-oct-13'
      group by account_no
     ) a;
```

Some notes.  `order by` in a subquery or CTE is not useful, unless you are selecting `rownum` in the next outer query.  If you want the results ordered, then put an `order by` in the outer query.

The query itself doesn't make sense.  Why would the opening balance come from the previous account number?  Usually such terminology is used for dates on a particular account, and you have eliminated all dates in the `group by` clause.

Comment: same result opening and closing always show 0 zero

Comment: @user3244687 . . . As mentioned, I didn't change your query.  I just commented that it doesn't make sense.  Why would you be taking a balance from another account?

Answer (score 1):

You keep changing your requirements, but based on what you shown at the moment, this works:

```
select account_no,
 max(opening) keep (dense_rank first order by gdate) as opening,
 sum(debit) as debit,
 sum(credit) as credit,
 max(closing) keep (dense_rank first order by gdate desc) as closing
from (
 select account_no, gdate, credit, debit,
 lag(balance, 1, 0) over (partition by account_no order by gdate) as opening,
 balance as closing
 from (
  select account_no, gdate, debit, credit,
  sum(debit) over (partition by account_no order by gdate) as sum_debit,
  sum(credit) over (partition by account_no order by gdate) as sum_credit,
  sum(credit) over (partition by account_no order by gdate)
   - sum(debit) over (partition by account_no order by gdate) as balance
  from ledger
 )
)
where gdate > date '2013-10-02'
group by account_no
order by account_no;
```

Which is the same logic I linked to before, when you had different data. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7b79a/27).

I'm not sure why you're showing your opening balance as positive though; seems wrong when all you have are debits. If that really is what you want then just swap how the balance is calculated:

```
...
  sum(debit) over (partition by account_no order by gdate)
   - sum(credit) over (partition by account_no order by gdate) as balance
...
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7b79a/28).