# Query For Opening And Closing Balance In Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

hi i have following table and data to get opening and closing balance of every account opening balance required gdate<02-oct-2013 here is my table

```
create table ledger (account_no varchar2(10),gdate date,debit number(8),credit number(8))

insert into ledger (account_no,gdate,debit,credit) values ('10-0001','01-oct-2013',1000,0);
insert into ledger (account_no,gdate,debit,credit) values ('10-0001','24-oct-2013',0,440);
insert into ledger (account_no,gdate,debit,credit) values ('20-0001','01-oct-2013',3000,0);
insert into ledger (account_no,gdate,debit,credit) values ('30-0001','01-oct-2013',300,0);
insert into ledger (account_no,gdate,debit,credit) values ('20-0001','16-oct-2013',1200,0);
insert into ledger (account_no,gdate,debit,credit) values ('30-0001','17-oct-2013',0,1340);
insert into ledger (account_no,gdate,debit,credit) values ('30-0001','24-oct-2013',500,0);
```

i need following result

```
ACCOUNT_NO OPENING  DEBIT  CREDIT  CLOSING
10-0001    1000    0       440    560
20-0001    3000    1200      0    4200
30-0001     300    500    1340    540
```

Comment: boss output is not enough.. try to elaborate what you want...

Comment: Please don't [ask the same question twice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21407259/266304).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
with tab as (select l.*,
                    dense_rank() over (partition by l.account_no order by l.gdate) min_date
               from ledger l),
tab2 as (select tab.*, 
                sum(case when min_date <> 1 then debit else 0 end) over (partition by account_no) t_debit,
                sum(case when min_date <> 1 then credit else 0 end) over (partition by account_no) t_credit
           from tab)
select ACCOUNT_NO , 
       DEBIT as opening, 
       T_DEBIT as DEBIT, 
       T_CREDIT as CREDIT, 
       (DEBIT + T_DEBIT - T_CREDIT) closing
  from tab2
 where min_date = 1;
```

Ouput:

```
| ACCOUNT_NO | OPENING | T_DEBIT | T_CREDIT | CLOSING |
|------------|---------|---------|----------|---------|
|    10-0001 |    1000 |       0 |      440 |     560 |
|    20-0001 |    3000 |    1200 |        0 |    4200 |
|    30-0001 |     300 |     500 |     1340 |    -540 |
```

However, in you illustration, closing for last account is 540, but it should be -540

EDIT:
If for a particular date output id required then:

```
with tab as (select l.ACCOUNT_NO,
                    sum(case when gdate < '02-OCT-2013' then (debit - credit) else 0 end) opening,
                    sum(case when gdate >= '02-OCT-2013' then debit else 0 end) t_debit,
                    sum(case when gdate >= '02-OCT-2013' then credit else 0 end) t_credit
               from ledger l
              group by l.ACCOUNT_NO)
select ACCOUNT_NO , 
       opening, 
       T_DEBIT as debit, 
       T_CREDIT as credit, 
       (opening + T_DEBIT - T_CREDIT) closing
  from tab
order by 1;
```

Comment: san if gdate<'02/10/2013' more than multiple entries than it show multiple results

Comment: Is it like you are using gdate<'02/10/2013' condition for opening balance only for each month? I don't understand the use of this condition..

Comment: San if 10-0001 account have 10 records before 02/10/2013 it sum all debit-credit entries and show me in opening balance

Comment: Check the answer and let me know if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT x.*, (x.Opening + x.Debit - x.Credit) as "CLOSING"
FROM (
    SELECT l.ACCOUNT_NO as "ACCOUNT_NO",
        (SELECT DEBIT FROM ledger l2 
         WHERE l2.ACCOUNT_NO = l.ACCOUNT_NO AND l2.gdate < '02/10/2013') as "OPENING"
        SUM(l.DEBIT) as "DEBIT", SUM(l.CREDIT) as "CREDIT" 
    FROM ledger as l
    GROUP BY l.ACCOUNT_NO
) as x
```

Comment: this query show error ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: This is not valid (standard) SQL.